# Application in kotlin enum

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-application-class

Is it safe if I use application in a kotlin `enum`? Like this:

```
enum class Labels(title: String, type: Int) {
     PERFORM(App.application.getString(R.string.perform), 0),
     DUTY(App.application.getString(R.string.duty), 1),
     ... ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only thing you need to worry about is whether those values can be retrieved at the time the `enum` class is first loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `App` class in the `enum`. Instead I would pass only resource id, because we can't rely that `App` class is instantiated at the moment of enum class is first loaded:

```
enum class Labels(val titleResId: Int, val type: Int) {
   PERFORM(R.string.perform, 0),
   DUTY(R.string.duty, 1),
   ... ...
}
```

And later we can use it, for example in `Activity`, like this:

```
textView.setText(Labels.PERFORM.titleResId)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,I'm going to revise my code. And , someone told me, enum is a static field, so i should not put context in